# Event trigger in Alexa without voice request?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Is there a way to activate an event Alexa without speaking?
For instance, I am working on a project involving a pill box, and once it is set up, I want Alexa to remind me to take my medication without requiring a vocal command from me

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into [Routines](https://www.amazon.com/alexa-routines/b?ie=UTF8&node=21442922011)? This would let you schedule time-based actions like Alexa-spoken reminders.

If you're building a custom skill, [the Reminders API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html) would give you a way to programmatically setup spoken reminders as well.

There's also [the Alexa Routines Kit](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/alexaroutineskit) skills can use to create Routines by voice, but this is in developer preview, so you would need to apply for access.